# Region conflict in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ubuntu-14.04, s3cmd

I have bucket in the region EU (London) in S3. I am trying to upload a tar file  through command line. At the end it throws an error saying so

`A client error (PermanentRedirect) occurred when calling the PutObject operation: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint.Please send all future requests to this endpoint.`

I have correctly configured using `aws configure` by giving correct access key and Region. Can someone shed light into this issue

I have created a script to upload database by creating a tar file

```
HOST=abc.com
DBNAME=db
BUCKET=s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/
USER=<user>
stamp=`date +"%Y-%m-%d"`
filename="Mgdb_$stamp.tar.gz"
TIME=`/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d-%T`
DEST=/home/$USER/tmp
TAR=$DEST/../$TIME.tar.gz
/bin/mkdir -p $DEST
echo "Backing up $HOST/$DBNAME to s3://$BUCKET/ on $TIME";
/usr/bin/mongodump --host $HOST --port 1234 -u "user" -p "pass"    --authenticationDatabase "admin"  -o $DEST
/bin/tar czvf $TAR -C $DEST .
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp $TAR s3://$BUCKET/$stamp/$filename
/bin/rm -f $TAR
/bin/rm -rf $DEST
```

Comment: I have also confirmed that the region is EU (London) by having it checked in aws console as well.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to upload to the S3 bucket?

Comment: @junkangli I have shared the script

Comment: The format for the S3Uri in your script is incorrect. It should be `s3://<bucketname>/<prefix>/<filename>`. Then you add the `--region` option to specify the bucket region.

Comment: @junkangli Can you tell me what `<prefix>` is in your comment?

Comment: that would be your $stamp variable.

Comment: Your problem is: `BUCKET=s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/<bucketname>/` This is not the name of your bucket. It should be `BUCKET=bucketname`

Answer (score 1):

Just append the region to the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) command:

```
aws s3 cp file.txt s3://my-bucket/file.txt --region eu-west-2
```

Comment: I tried appending the region. awscli returned saying,
 `eu-west-2 is invalid maybe you meant eu-west-1`.
I added `eu-west-1`, it returned the same error in the question.

Comment: @darshankrishnaiah if `eu-west-2 is invalid`, you need a newer version of the cli that supports it.

Comment: `pip install awscli --upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

The format for the S3Uri in your script is incorrect. It should be `s3://<bucketname>/<prefix>/<filename>`. Then you add the `--region` option to specify the bucket region.

```
$BUCKET=<bucketname>
/usr/bin/aws s3 cp $TAR s3://$BUCKET/$stamp/$filename --region eu-west-2
```

Comment: Perhaps try to troubleshoot by issuing the command without the variables first. Additionally, double check the name of your bucket, as well as the AWS credentials - ensure the account has access to the bucket.